# Create a symlink building an Android image

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

I'm writing the definition of a new device and product to build a custom Android image and I need to create a symbolic link while building the image, but it's not clear what's the correct way to do it in an Android *mk* file.

As an example, let's say that I need to create a link named *wget* that points to the executable *busybox* in the */system/bin* directory.

Using a call to a *shell* command like the following may work, but it's heavily discouraged since it's executed multiple times, when the mk file is parsed (and so is applied also on the host system):

```
$(shell ln -frs $(TARGET_OUT_EXECUTABLES)/busybox $(TARGET_OUT_EXECUTABLES)/wget)
```

Another approach that I tried was to populate a directory tree like this:

```
$ tree device/my_vendor/my_device/links
links
└── system
    └── bin
        └── wget -> busybox
```

and then use this code:

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES += \
        $(call find-copy-subdir-files,*,device/my_vendor/my_device/links,$(TARGET_COPY_OUT_ROOT))
```

but no file at all is created in the image, and there is nothing in the logs.

So, **what's the correct way to add a symlink, creating an Android image?**

Bonus question: how to create a link that will reside in the root? Something like */link* pointing to */vendor/directory*, for example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD (for all type modules) or LOCAL_POST_LINK_CMD (only for executable)

1. LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD [example](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/rootdir/Android.mk#88)
2. LOCAL_POST_LINK_CMD [example](https://zh.osdn.net/projects/android-x86/scm/git/system-core/commits/172111e3c16aea4eca74c5a1493226235843a465)

Comment: that's interesting! I will try it and let you know if it works

Comment: I tried `LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD += ; ln -sf /destination-of-symlink $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/name-of-symlink`, following the examples in build/make/core, but it doesn't seem to work and there is nothing in the logs (clean build). That's strange.

Comment: Can you make sure that the destination-of-symlink is existed when the command is excuted.

Comment: yep, for my tests I'm using /vendor $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/link-to-vendor so I'm sure it exists. I'm adding the LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD to my product mk file; should it be elsewhere?  Thanks!

Comment: What do your mean product mk file. It should be in a Android.mk, not device.mk

Comment: you were right, I can confirm it works. The correct syntax is `LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD += ln -sf /destination-of-symlink $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/name-of-symlink ;` in an Android.mk file.

Answer (score 1):

A standard way to do this is in 'runtime' during boot via `init.rc` files.

The syntax for it according to [init/README.md](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md) is:

> `symlink <target> <path>`
> Create a symbolic link at path with the value target

There might some other way to do this in *"build time"*, but I haven't encountered it yet, and I've seen lots of parts of AOSP use the `init.rc` way.

Comment: thanks; I was looking for a way to do it at build time, but you may be right and doing it at boot could be the only (sane) way.